# How to delete a keys in memcached with regex (using Dalli+RoR).

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memcached, ruby-on-rails-3.2, dalli

How to delete a keys in memcached with regex (using Dalli+Rails)

```
  def expire_all
   expire_fragment(Regexp.new("/customers/customers"))
   expire_fragment(Regexp.new("/customers/customers\/"))
   expire_fragment(Regexp.new("/agreements/agreements"))
   expire_fragment(Regexp.new("/agreements/agreements\/"))
  end
```

Not working with memcached. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install gem dalli-store-extensions
https://github.com/defconomicron/dalli-store-extensions

In the Sweeper

```
expire_fragment /#{Regexp.escape(restaurant.id)}\/stocks*/
```

Comment: dalli-store-extensions uses a local memory cache, so it can get out of synch between app instances. (i think that's the issue). see my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998762/expiring-memcache-via-regex

Comment: There are also significant performance issues with constantly serializing and deserializing a key set when writing and deleting keys.

Answer (score 3):

Memcached isn't able to iterate over its keys, so regexp expiration won't work. See [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Fragments.html#method-i-expire_fragment).

Take a look at [this](http://quickleft.com/blog/faking-regex-based-cache-keys-in-rails) for a potential workaround, though it's labor intensive.